# "ImportError: cannot import name _imaging" after using PyInstaller (Python 2)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I have code that I'm writing in Python 2 that works just fine when run from Python, but after I send the script through PyInstaller, and run the executable, it spits out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/ben/Documents/Programming/Python/Weasyl/Test Scripts/build/test3/out00-PYZ.pyz/PIL.PngImagePlugin", line 40, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/ben/Documents/Programming/Python/Weasyl/Test Scripts/build/test3/out00-PYZ.pyz/PIL.Image", line 53, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

I'm not completely sure why it's having issues importing this module, as the PyInstaller lists Tkinter and PIL as compatible. The code, in it's entirety, is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()
name = Label(root, text="(username)", font="Arial 20")
name.grid(row=0, column=0)
status = Label(root, text="(login status)")
status.grid(row=1, column=0)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(".avatar.png"))
panel = Label(root, image=img, relief=RAISED, height=100, width=100)
panel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm assuming the issue is with the `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`, but there's no way around using that module, because the image I want to use is PNG format, and as far as I know, Tkinter only supports GIF format outside of using that module.

EDIT: If I cannot use this module with PyInstaller, is there a way to get PNG images to display in Tkinter outside of this module?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with a similar problem. The PIL module Imaging isn't working, though PyInstaller doesn't seem to complain.
However, it only happened to me after I updated to Linux Mint 17. Used Mint 15 before, and the program compiled and worked fine there.

I guess I'm going to try an older version of PIL or some other method of loading textures...

**UPDATE:**
OK, good news!
Seems like the problem has been fixed in the current development version of PyInstaller. It can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

I've also tried changing all my texturing code to use PyGame instead of PIL (since I was using it in my program anyway), however there was also trouble running PyGame after making the executable with PyInstaller 2.1.

With the current development version of PyInstaller from GitHub, however, both PyGame and PIL work fine!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Hasturkun - I don't think this is asking another question. He mentions having a similar problem, but then solving it by using a different version. I think the best reason for deleting this is because it's more of an aside or comment than an answer to this question.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: It's not an answer. It should either be a comment or a separate question. I just picked the closest stock comment for this case.

Comment: OK, I've managed to get my program working now and updated the post. :)

Comment: @XArgon How do you install development version?

Comment: @napkinsterror - There's no need to install it, you can just download it from GitHub (the link I gave above) and use it right away (probably run the setup.py script, and then use "pyinstaller.py" as usual)